# crond won't start. Problem with temp directory /run/cron?

Tags: linux, cron, slackware

A week ago I updated my wife's computer, and after a few days noticed that `crond` wasn't running. Running `crond -d` wasn't much useful, so I ran strace crond -d`. This error appears:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_RDWR)   = 0
dup2(0, 0)                              = 0
dup2(0, 1)                              = 1
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1dab000
brk(0x1dcc000)                          = 0x1dcc000
getpid()                                = 1405
mkdir("/run/cron/cron.I23Z7s", 0700)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
dup(2)                                  = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
write(3, "mkdtemp: No such file or directo"..., 35mkdtemp: No such file or directory
```

BTW, OS is Slackware64-current.

**Extra info:**
I just detected that I can start `rc.crond` manually (as root), but it doesn't start when rebooting... and it works correctly, executing all the cron tasks.

Comment: does the directory /run/cron exist and have permissions that allow cron to create temp files?

Comment: It did have permissions, and the directory seems to be generated on boot. But the problem was different, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion on the `##slackware` IRC channel about how this problem could occur, I noticed that there was a difference in the `/etc/rc.d/rc.M` file in my computer and the one at one of the participants.

Older versions of `Slackware` seem to manage the `crond` startup directly, while newer versions do this task indirectly by calling `rc.crond start`. `rc.crond` does some extra work. Normally this should have been updated automatically, but, for some reason, it wasn't (the `rc.M.new` hadn't replaced the original file).